# Java Binary Tree Search Order Left Side Not Working

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to confirm that the Search Tree is following the sorting rules (smaller numbers to the left and bigger numbers to the right).
This is working fine (recursively) for the right side, but the left side is off.

When the tree looks like this:

> ```
>            100                 
>      50            150
>   55   75       125   175
> ```

If I print the output, I can see that it checks that 50 < 100 and that 150 > 100, then it moves down the right side and checks that 125 < 150 and 175 > 150. It checks 125 and 175, but afterwards jumps to 55 and 75 and never compares 55 < 50 (false) and 75 > 50.

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
    public boolean isSearchTree(){
    boolean result = true;

    if (left != null) result = left.isSearchTree();
    if (right != null) result = right.isSearchTree();

    if (left != null && left.value >= value ){
        return false;
    } 
    if (right != null && right.value <= value ){
        return false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the `result` from the left tree here:

```
if (right != null) result = right.isSearchTree();
```

Make a shortcut:

```
if (!left.isSearchTree()) {
  return false;
}

if (!right.isSearchTree()) {
  return false;
}

if (left != null && left.value >= value ){
  return false;
} 

if (right != null && right.value <= value ){
  return false;
}

return true;
```